# Connection with MS Access 2010 via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, database-connection

```
Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

newRow.Item(1) = Student_IDTextBox.Text
newRow.Item(2) = Student_NameTextBox.Text
newRow.Item(3) = Date_of_BirthDateTimePicker.Text
newRow.Item(4) = AddressTextBox.Text
newRow.Item(5) = E_mailTextBox.Text
newRow.Item(6) = AllergiesTextBox.Text
newRow.Item(7) = Emergency_Contact_NumberTextBox.Text

dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

The line 
`newRow.Item(2) = Student_NameTextBox.Text`
gives a error saying:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Couldn't store <> in Date of Birth Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

But I checked the database the second row is the Student name Field.

I think the code is starting to input the student name into the student ID field in the database, The Student Id is the primary key coe this be why it isn't storing the `student_IDtextbox` data in its specified field?

I realy need help with this my project is due in about 9 days!

Answer (score 1):

the columns index in DataRow class, Similar all indexs in vb.net, its zero-based.
first column is zero, second one and ect.

Comment: Also, because you used `SELECT *`, you are not guaranteed to order of your fields, you should spell out your field names in your select.  IE, `SELECT ID,Student_Name,Etc.. FROM ...`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working nw but another line has given me yet another error: `da.Update(dt)`